# JSON not generated in using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm using the latest version of Jersey to implement some REST sample services.
Do you have any clue why when I generate the following HTTP request using Fiddler,I get:
 `500 Internal Server Error`

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type={application/json, q=1000}, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<com.example.Todo>
```

HTTP request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/RestProject/rest/todos/1 HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Host: localhost:8080
```

That's the Rest method getting called:

```
 //This method is called if XML or JSON is requested  
  @GET  
  @Path("{id}")  
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_XML})  
  public Todo getEntityXMLOrJSON(@PathParam("id") int id)  
  {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first todo " + id);
    todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
    return todo;
  }
```

When I request xml data everything works fine.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I think that this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518996/jersey-json-serialization

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace you can show us. Generally a 500 will mean an exception is thrown an in most cases is logged

Comment: Also can you list all your dependencies/jars

Comment: yes:MessageBodyWriter not found for media type={application/json, q=1000}, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<com.example.Todo>.

Comment: The exact same exception is raised when you register the JacksonJsonProvider? This would look like it has not been recongized by jersey then.

Comment: Keep only the jars you saw in the tutorial.  Take everything else out. Then find and add [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29136934/2587435). It should work.

Comment: And are you sure this is the code that corresponds to the error you're showing us? Because the error is about trying to marshal an `ArrayList<Todo>`. So simple have a `Todo` you are returning.

Comment: still not genereting json...but now i get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect

Comment: thanks, @peeskillet now it works fine,could you make your comments an answer so that I can accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty familiar with the Vogella tutorial. So many people have posted about it. It uses Jersey 2. You are trying to add some Jersey 1 jars to the project. Take all the ones you added on your own out. Then find and add these

[image]

And if you're using web.xml, then register the provider like so

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>
    com.jersey.jaxb,com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
</param-value>
```

adding an init param to the jersey servlet. Otherwise, using Java config, in your `ResourceConfig`, just

```
register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```

That's for JAXB annotation support. If you don't need it, then you can just use `JacksonJsonProvider`

Comment: If I use jersey 2 then all these jackson jars would not be needed, right ?

Comment: You _are_ using Jersey 2. The main thing you need a is a provider, which is the `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. But that jar is dependent on all the other jars. These are basic Jackson jars. The provider can't live on its own

Comment: With Jersey 1, would use the `jersey-json` you tried to add. But even that is dependent on some Jackson jars, which you do not have

Answer (score 0):

My solution was adding the following dependencies;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>your jersey version</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>your jersey version</version>
</dependency>
```