# return Map from rest service in json format

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have a method which is returning `Map<String, ArrayList<EntityClass>>`. code is as follow of `Definition` class:

```
public Map<String, ArrayList<EntityClass>> webMethod1(){
    ArrayList<EntityClass> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        arr.add(new EntityClass(i, String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    Map<String, ArrayList<EntityClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Entity", arr);
}
```

Further this is called by a web service as follow:

```
@GET
@Path("/m1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, ArrayList<EntityClass>> m1(){
    return new Definition().webMethod1();
}
```

but i am getting following on the console:

`MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=class java.util.HashMap.`

and `HTTP 500` as error.

how to resolve this error

Comment: You need to transform you `Map` into json, with whatever wrapper/class Jersey is offering you.

Comment: i am newbie to this, can you explain it in detail

Comment: Have you read the documentation?https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/json.html

Comment: Which Jersey version are you using? 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: See also [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26518996/1098603). A little search cannot be bad...

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin 2.x

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37250802/1426227) will be useful.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin that did not work

Comment: Can you clarify *that did not work*?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin first i am not using maven, second that question you told, in that, error is because of moxy jar as i faced the same error. mine in different because maps are not top level element in json, we have to implement at our own, by using MessageBodyWriter in jersey.

Comment: Get rid of moxy and use [Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435). Moxy sucks with Maps

Answer (score 2):

May be you should consider using a simple marshaller library like GSON.
I end up with this code :

```
@GET
@Path("/m1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String webMethod1(){
    ArrayList<EntityClass> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        arr.add(new EntityClass(i, "\"-'"+String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    Map<String, List<EntityClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Entity", arr);

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    return gson.toJson(map);
}
```

This does the job pretty well to me and don't add a lot of complexity as writing a `MessageBodyWriter` which is pointless for simple POJO classes and structures.